# jPlayer stops in the middle of track and starts repeating a section of the track

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, audio-streaming, jplayer

I use jPlayer 2.7.1 (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.7.1/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js) on my website to play audio tracks for users. The audio tracks come from an S3 bucket. Recently some users who access the website via an Android WebView that utilizes Chrome Mobile 30, 44, 45 are having issues playing the audio files.

The common complaint seems to be a variation of the track starting to play, and then at some point it gets stuck, skipping or lagging over the remaining audio. Some specific quotes from users:

> "after several minutes the sound stop and repeat on the same word it
>   is like sort of lagging."
>
> "when I press play, the recording plays in second snippets (sort of
>   like it is very slowly loading), very disjointed. The time bar also
>   does not progress, it just stays at 0:00 or sometimes to 0:01 and back
>   again, even though it's playing later parts of the recording."
>
> "the audio plays a few seconds, stops, skips a lot of content, plays
>   for another second or two, stops, skips, and so on."
>
> "If it does start it keeps cutting out/crackling sound and the time
>   doesn't start counting down."

Unfortunately I've been unable to recreate the issue myself.

What do you think could be causing this issue? Could moving to jPlayer 2.9.2 fix the issue?

Comment: same issue, while using 2.9.2

Comment: same with me. upgrading to 2.9.2 didn't make a difference.